# New list from other list

Tags: c#, list

So, the problem is as I go trough the loops I am creating tempNumberList, and then after it goes into if (true) statement it adds variable to tempNumberList, but when I add it, somehow lineVarList also adds same variable to itself.

I don't know what to even search for. I don't think is is very hard, but I don't have any idea what is going on.

```
if (checkedNumbersResult)
{
     finalResult.MaximumNumber = pyramidNumbers.First().First();
     finalResult.NumbersInLine.Add(pyramidNumbers.First());
     AssignmentResult notBranchingResults = new AssignmentResult
     {
         MaximumNumber = pyramidNumbers.First().First(),
         NumbersInLine = new List<List<int>>()
     };
     foreach (var pyramidNumberList in pyramidNumbers.Skip(1))
     {
         List<List<int>> tempNumberList = new List<List<int>>();
         foreach (var lineVarList in finalResult.NumbersInLine)
         {
             List<int> tempVarlist = lineVarList;
             for (int varListItem = 0; varListItem < lineVarList.Count(); varListItem++)
             {
                 if (true)
                 {
                     tempVarlist.Add(pyramidNumberList.Skip(varListItem).First());
                     tempNumberList.Add(tempVarlist);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, accidentally wrote same code in SO twice.... Edited code.

Comment: perfect time to learn how to use debugger. put a break point on the most outer loop and then go one line at a time. use a pen and paper to write down expected values and check against values at run time. If you found the line causing unexpected behavior and still can't figure out why then you can come back again. Good luck :)

Comment: The cure for `I don't have any idea what is going on` is some time with the [Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)

Comment: `List<int> tempVarlist = lineVarList;` is just assigning the reference held by `lineVarList` to `tempVarlist1`, so they're both pointing to the same memory location (the same list). To create a new list that's a copy of the original, you can do `List<int> tempVarlist = lineVarList.ToList();` or `List<int> tempVarlist = new List<int> (lineVarList);`

Comment: List<int> tempVarlist = lineVarList.ToList() this is very interesting. Because in for loop it is already list. But with this .ToList() extension everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# all the object are send by reference. When you do

```
List<int> tempVarlist = lineVarList;
```

you actually send a reference to `tempVarlist` and that means you don't create a new object. You pass the address of `lineVarList` to `tempVarlist` so the both of them are pointing to the same address. The result will be the one you just observed. You practically use the same object but with two different names. This is the reason why your actions are affect both lists.